# Y axis is cut with axis function

Tags: r, bar-chart, axis

I am plotting two variables using barplot. Everything is working fine except that when I add the left y axis, the values are out of range and it is cut. I tried to see if I should fix the graphics view using  `par` but it did not work.
Here is my script

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(prey[, c("weasels", "voles")])), axisnames=FALSE,names.arg=NULL,yaxt= "n",beside  = TRUE)
axis(1, cex.axis=0.8, at = c(2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26),line=0.4,labels = c("2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2014","2015","2016"), 2)
axis(2, cex.axis=0.8,at = c(0, 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40),labels = round(c(0, 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40)), 2)
axis(4, cex.axis=0.8,at = c(0, 5,10,15,20,25,30),labels = round(c(0, 5,10,15,20,25,30)), 2)
```

Image of the Plot I made:

[image: Plot I made]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the limits of your barplot by using the ylim parameter :

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(prey[, c("weasels", "voles")])), axisnames=FALSE,names.arg=NULL,yaxt= "n",beside  = TRUE, ylim=c(0,40))
```

Comment: Thank you @Dash. I still have one question if you might know the answer. I added a plot to my barplot. I added a y-axis to this plot but it doesn't fit the scale of the barplot's y-axis. It is a bit shifted.

Comment: Here is the script `barplot(t(as.matrix(prey[, c("weasels", "voles")])), cex.axis=0.8,ylim=c(0,35),axisnames=FALSE,names.arg=NULL,beside  = TRUE)
x=axis(1, cex.axis=0.8, at = c(2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26),line=0.4,labels = c("2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2014","2015","2016"), 2)
par(new=T)
plot(prey$snow, xaxt="n", lty=3,lwd=2,col=c("black"),yaxt="n",ylab = "", xlab="", type="c",frame=F, ylim = c(0,120))
points(prey$snow, col="darkblue", lwd=2)
axis(4, cex.axis=0.8,yaxp=c(0, 35, by=7),at = seq(0, 120, by=10),labels = seq(0, 120, by=10), 2)`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem, but I'll try to answer anyway with a tips for barplot. For example 
`barplot(c(3,4,2,5,6))`
Doesn't draw bars at the x-coordinates of 1,2,3,4,5, but instead at the x-coordinates of 0.7, 1.9, 3.1, 4.3, 5.5. The x-coordinates can be obtained by
`x_coord <- barplot(c(3,4,2,5,6))`
This can be useful to fit the additional elements to your barplot.

Comment: Thanks @Dash. I will try to see if this works out or not.